# MaterialDesign resource not found

Tags: wpf, material-design, .net-6.0

I have a **wpf** project with **.net6** and I have added materialdesign according to the [document](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/)
When I copy the xaml code from the toolkit > This Image:

[image: from the toolkit]

and add it to the source, it encounters the error in the image below that it does not find the resource, while the same process is performed and executed with .net framework 4.8 without any problem or error.
Please advise where I am having problems?

[image: MaterialDesign resource not found ...]